# How to get and send response Binance API Withdraw using node.js

Tags: node.js, api, development-environment, trend, binance-api-client

I'm trying to withdraw spot wallet crypto of binance account using API and using node.js connector.

This is my code:

```
client.withdraw('USDT', 'wallet_address', 20, { network: 'BSC'})
    .then(response => client.logger.log(response))
    .catch(error => client.logger.error(error));

res.send(response);
```

It is working fine and returning the json format response in terminal, but when I use postman to get response there, in postman response I get nothing in response while the terminal is showing json format response perfectly. what could be the reason?

Answer (score -1):

Are you setting apiKey and secretKey in postman?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).